# Why can the monster switch dimensions at will?

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-things

In *Stranger Things*, the dimension door in the electric power station is created by 011, but apparently the monster can switch dimensions at will (like in the Byers house or the trunk). If the monster can switch dimensions at will the whole thing that the girl created a dimension door that has to be closed is absolutely meaningless and the monster must have been able to come into 'this' dimension before 011 created the dimension door.

Are there any answers to this questions in the series or by the director? I could not find anything about it yet.

Comment: Nobody could switch dimensions at will. El caused something more then one gate - whole area became like cheese, with temporary holes between worlds.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that El touching the monster accomplished a couple things, in addition to creating the initial portal. First, I think the monster was not aware of the parallel world before that, if the world was even "that" parallel before the touch.

But more importantly, the touch and El's reaction generated sufficient energy to align the worlds (think of Mr Clarke's folded paper example). After this event, at times, people in the same place in the real and upside-down worlds could sometimes hear and/or sense one another.

To me, this indicates such a close association between the two dimensions, that the monster -- especially when sensing blood -- can create new ways to cross that barrier.

I wouldn't necessarily call the monster's crossing effortless; we've seen a couple times when it had to make some effort to get through a wall or ceiling. Though the passage through the tree was different somehow; I'm not sure why.

Also, recall the scene where Will was able to get close to coming through the wall in his house (the place where Joyce subsequently took an axe to). Perhaps the only difference between Will not being able to actually break through, and the monster being able to, is strength. We are told that the atmosphere is poison to humans and we see Will's weakness, but he still got kinda close.

Comment: some interesting commentary about the monster being like a shark, http://www.vice.com/en_ca/read/the-man-who-played-the-monster-in-stranger-things.      -----> The simple directions the Duffers gave me were, "You're basically a shark, like the shark from Jaws, and you travel between realms to feed." So that was my main goal in this character.